# How to debug with Conditional in a webservice?

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a webservice that, if appropriate, sends out error messages.

I would like those error messages to be pretty limited ("Internal crash") in production mode, and pretty thorough in debug mode.

I thought about using `[Conditional("DEBUG")]`, but it only works with *methods returning void*.

Do I really have to use `#ifdef` around my error messaging, or black arcane magicking (like using said conditional method to tell the webservice object to get into a "debug mode", which seems rather ugly to me, as it's imho not something the object should be aware of at all)?

Is there a trick or appropriate method I'm unaware of?

Comment: u better try that same process in some sample.cs file while debug mode so that u can find the problem ...

Comment: There is no problem currently. It's a design question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup a behavior in WCF that catches all exceptions and then removes most of the error information if you are in the production mode. You can setup the mode with a flag in the web.config file.

Comment: Yeah, I know that one, but the webservice itself is sending specific error information (client requirement). Currently I'm doing the "black magic" trick which seems a bit safer than #ifdef, but the webconfig solution will not change what exceptions my code catches and forwards, right?

Comment: you don't need to rethrow the actual exception, you can log it on the server side and throw a new FaultException with much less detail. A possibility might be to setup a dictionary by exception type and the message you want to send. If you don't get a match you can just send the "internal crash" message. That way you would never send out too detailed info

Comment: Though, if in debug mode, I do want to send out detailed info. It is in the end less a question of exceptions than it is of writing stuff to an object when using DEBUG mode. I think one solution would be to have the response object passed in to the conditional method, and modified by it?

Comment: If you create your own exception class you can have a friendly message field which is the only thing you send out if it's production mode and in all other cases you send the full exception. Then it will be easy to control and you'll get the full error in debug mode.